# Realm not emiting data after insertOrUpdate

Tags: android, realm, rx-java

I'm using Firebase for notifications. 
As you may know, each push token from firebase is generated for each application instance (roughly).

So firstly, I'm storing this token within Realm database. On successful login I call this:

```
 private void updatePushToken(final RealmUser user) {
        String pushToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        final RealmPushToken token = getPushToken();

        token.setUserId(user.getId());
        token.setToken(pushToken);

        replacePushToken(token, null);
    }

   public void replacePushToken(@Nullable final RealmPushToken token, @Nullable OnInsertListener listener) {
    Realm instance = getRealmInstance();
    instance.executeTransactionAsync(realm -> {
                realm.delete(RealmPushToken.class);
                if (token != null) {
                    realm.insertOrUpdate(token);
                }
            }, /*listeners*/);
    }


    public RealmPushToken getPushToken() {
        try (Realm instance = getRealmInstance()) {
            RealmResults<RealmPushToken> tokens = instance.where(RealmPushToken.class).findAll();
            if (!tokens.isEmpty()) {
                return instance.copyFromRealm(tokens.first());
            }
            return new RealmPushToken();
        }
    }
```

And meanwhile I'm launching Service that (in theory) should monitor changes based on the RealmPushToken class:

```
/* Launched in onCreate */
private void subscribeToPushToken() {
    Subscription subscription = getPushTokenAsync()
            .subscribeOn(immediateThread)
            .observeOn(uiThread)
            .subscribe(token -> {
                //Send token to backend
                    }, throwable -> {
                    //Log
                    }
            );

    compositeSubscription.add(subscription);
}


public Observable<RealmPushToken> getPushTokenAsync() {
    Realm instance = getRealmInstance();

    return instance.where(RealmPushToken.class)
            .findAllAsync()
            .asObservable()
            .filter(o -> o.isLoaded() && o.isValid())
            .map(tokens -> tokens.isEmpty() ? new RealmPushToken() : tokens.first())
            .doOnUnsubscribe(instance::close);
}
```

And - when I'm looking at this design, for me it should be fired everytime i launch replacePushToken in the first snipped (assuming that it went successful, which usually is). 
What's going on is that the Observable does not emit any items :/
It means that the service isn't notified about the change, therefore I'm not sending new token to the backend, which means that I'm not receiving any notifications.

I have two suspicions

a. Realm does not think that this is a change significant enough to care.

b. There is something going on with a old realm version, threads and so on.

Am I missing something?

EDIT:

```
import static io.realm.Realm.getDefaultInstance;

private Realm getRealmInstance() {
    return getDefaultInstance();
}
```

Comment: Depending on what `getRealmInstance()` does, you might be closing the Realm if you call `getPushToken()`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I forgot to add, that all methods (i.e. getPushTokenAsync(), getRealmInstance(), replacePushToken() and getPushToken() are called from the same Dagger singleton DatabaseManager. 

And I'm always using Realm.getDefaultInstance().

Comment: Okay, questions: 1.) what is your Realm version, 2.) what is this `Service` you start, 3.) Is the `getRealmInstance()` obtained from a dagger component marked with `@Singleton`? (in your case, hopefully not)

Comment: @EpicPandaForce
1. 3.1.0

2. DatabaseService extending Service. And I'm subscribing in the onCreate. I'm quite sure that it's not dead when I'm performing updates. 
3. Unfortunately I'm launching everything from the @Singleton Dagger component. Both `insertOrUpdate` and `get...()` are located in it. (therefore the getRealmInstance(). I'll add the exact implementation in my root post.
How big of a problem that is?

Comment: It's only a problem if you close it somewhere because your singleton realm will get invalidated. Try removing that try-with-resources block for your getRealm

Comment: @EpicPandaForce but is that related to my problem? 

Because for some reason I'm not notified about the change and this makes my pretty neat flow... unreliable at least.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I can't edit my previous comment, but I understand now! I moved the subscription creation to something that starts a bit more "often". Because in my case, when user logs out I wasn't notifying the server about that. It was probably related to ... being subscribed to an old Realm instance. Am I right?

Comment: since you're monitoring the changes form a Service, you might be hitting this limitation https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#notifications

"ChangeListeners will not work in an IntentService. Even though it is a Looper thread, each invocation of onHandleIntent() is a separate event that doesn’t “loop”. This means that it is possible to register change listeners, but they will never be triggered."